# Unsigned long and bit shifting

Tags: c++, long-integer, unsigned

I have a problem with bit shifting and unsigned longs. Here's my test code:

```
char header[4];
header[0] = 0x80;
header[1] = 0x00;
header[2] = 0x00;
header[3] = 0x00;

unsigned long l1 = 0x80000000UL;
unsigned long l2 = ((unsigned long) header[0] << 24) + ((unsigned long) header[1] << 16) + ((unsigned long) header[2] << 8) + (unsigned long) header[3];

cout << l1 << endl;
cout << l2 << endl;
```

I would expect l2 to also have a value of 2147483648 but instead it prints 18446744071562067968. I assume the bit shifting of the first byte causes problems?

Hopefully somebody can explain why this fails and how I modify the calculation of l2 so that it returns the correct value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't reproduce. OS, CPU, compiler? BTW, you don't have to cast header[x] to unsigned long.

Comment: ... and if you do, you should use C++ casts.

Comment: Looks fine to me there: http://ideone.com/hKofC

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: Mac OS X, gcc v4.2.1

Comment: @Marcello Try printing the result of `sizeof(unsigned long)`.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: Why is the cast not necessary? I thought the resulting type of the shift operand is the type of the left operand. Which would be a char in case you dont cast (of course the final result would be unsigned long). Or did I miss something?

Comment: @Etienne `sizeof(unsigned long) == 8` so 64-bits like you mentioned below

Comment: @flolo The result is the type of the _promoted_ left operand. Integer promotions are performed on the char, making it an int, since the right-side operand is an int. So without the typecast all addition operations would be performed on ints and not unsigned longs, which sounds like a potential bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your value of 0x80 stored in a char is a signed quantity. When you cast this into a wider type, the value is being signed extended to keep the same value as a larger type.

Change the type of `char` in the first line to `unsigned char` and you will not get the sign extension happening.

To simplify what is happening in your case, run this:

```
char c = 0x80
unsigned long l = c
cout << l << endl;
```

You get this output:

```
18446744073709551488
```

which is -128 as a 64-bit integer (0x80 is -128 as a 8-bit integer).

Comment: You dont have sign extension when doing a left shift - it only happens when doing a right shift. When  it happen, is when you do the cast from char to unsigned long .

Answer (score 2):

Same result here (Linux/x86-64, GCC 4.4.5). The behavior depends on the size of `unsigned long`, which is *at least* 32 bits, but *may be larger*.

If you want exactly 32 bits, use a `uint32_t` instead (from the header `<stdint.h>`; not in C++03 but in the upcoming standard and widely supported).

Comment: Yep, looks like his implementation uses 64 bits for `unsigned long`.

Comment: Indeed `uint32_t` works. But how come the `unsigned long` fails; I do not exceed the 32 bits right?

Comment: @Marcello - try `std::cout << sizeof(unsigned long) << std::endl;`

Comment: I think this sums up the problem. The very first step towards becoming a professional programmer is to abandon the "hobbyist types": char, int, unsigned long etc. Use uintxx_t. If stdint.h isn't available because you are using C90 or C++, then make such a header yourself with typedefs.