# Bit-shifting unsigned longs in C

Tags: c, long-integer, bit-shift

I found a bug in a piece of code I wrote, and have fixed it, but still can't explain what was happening. It boils down to this:

```
unsigned i = 1<<31;          // gives 21476483648 as expected
unsigned long l = 1<<31;     // gives 18446744071562067968 as not expected
```

I'm aware of a question here: [Unsigned long and bit shifting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937332/unsigned-long-and-bit-shifting) wherein the exact same number shows up as an unexpected value, but there he was using a signed char which I believe led to a sign extension. I really can't for the life of me see why I'm getting an incorrect value here.

I'm using CLion on Ubuntu 18.04, and on my system an `unsigned` is 32 bits and a `long` is 64 bits.

Comment: `1` has type `int`. `1<<31` is equal to `( (int)1 << 31 )`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this expression:

```
1<<31
```

The value `1` has type `int`.  Assuming an `int` is 32 bits wide, that means you're shifting a bit into the sign bit.  Doing so is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This is documented in section 6.5.7p4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The  result  of **E1 << E2** is **E1** left-shifted **E2** bit  positions;  vacated 
>   bits  are  filled  with zeros.  If **E1** has  an  unsigned  type,  the 
>   value  of  the  result  is **E1×2<sup>E2</sup>**, reduced  modulo one  more  than  the 
>   maximum  value  representable  in  the  result  type.  If **E1** has  a 
>   signed type  and  nonnegative  value,  and **E1×2<sup>E2</sup>** is  representable  in 
>   the  result  type,  then  that  is the resulting value; otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined.

However, since you're on Ubuntu, which used GCC, the behavior is actually implementation defined.  The [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation) states:

> Bitwise operators act on the representation of the value including
>   both the sign and value bits, where the sign bit is considered
>   immediately above the highest-value value bit. Signed `>>` acts on
>   negative numbers by sign extension.
>
> As an extension to the C language, GCC does not use the latitude given
>   in C99 and C11 only to treat certain aspects of signed `<<` as
>   undefined. However, `-fsanitize=shift` (and `-fsanitize=undefined`) will
>   diagnose such cases. They are also diagnosed where constant
>   expressions are required.

So gcc in this case works directly on the representation of the values.  This means that `1<<31` has type `int` and the representation `0x80000000`.  The value of this representation in decimal is ‭-2147483648‬.

When this value is assigned to an `unsigned int`, it is converted via the rules in section 6.3.1.3p2:

> Otherwise,  if  the  new  type  is  unsigned,  the  value  is 
>   converted  by  repeatedly  adding  or subtracting  one  more  than  the
>   maximum  value  that  can  be  represented  in  the  new type until the
>   value is in the range of the new type.

Since "one more than the maximum value" is ‭42949672956 for a 32 bit `unsigned int`  This results in the `int` value -2147483648‬ being converted to the `unsigned int` value ‭42949672956 -2147483648 == 2147483648‬.

When  `1<<31` is assigned to an `unsigned long int` which is 64 bit, "one more than the maximum value" is 18446744073709551616 so the result of the conversion is 18446744073709551616 -2147483648 == 18446744071562067968, which is the value you're getting.

To get the correct value, use the `UL` suffix to make the value `unsigned long`:

```
1UL<<31
```